# How to input mutilple data types (int, float, string) in a loop and sort it into different lists in python?

Tags: python

I want input multiple data types and put them into lists.

Sample inputs of :

`-1,   0.5,   'abc',   32`

would lead to a final output of:

A= `[-1, 32]`,
B= `[0.5]`,
C= `['abc']`

I try to do it but every element is placed into list `C`

My code:

```
n = int(input("N = "))
lst = []
data = ""
for i in range(n):
    print("add element", i+1, ": ", end='')
    data = input()
    list(data)
    lst.append(data)
A = []
B = []
C = []
for x in lst:
    if isinstance(x, int):
        A.append(x)
    elif isinstance(x, float):
        B.append(x)
    else:
        C.append(x)
print("A = ", A)
print("B = ", B)
print("C = ", C)
```

Comment: Try to print every element of `lst`. The elements are string as `input()` returns string

Comment: `x` would be always a string, so `isinstance(x, int)` and `isinstance(x, float)` are `False`.

Comment: oh, tks how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all your input values are strings, the way to separate them is to try and convert them into the types you are trying to sort to. For example:

```py
A = []
B = []
C = []

lst = ['-1', '0.5', 'abc', '32']
for x in lst:
    try:
        A.append(int(x))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            B.append(float(x))
        except ValueError:
            C.append(x)

print(A, B, C)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 32] [0.5] ['abc']
```

Comment: thank you, so how to use loop to input different data type?

Comment: @realtun the loop that is already in your code will work fine. But all the input values will be strings as that is what [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns

Comment: @realtun, you can kept the loop for input as it is. Only remove the line `list(data)` as it doesn't do anything. Or you can remove the use of extra list `lst` and loop. Just use single loop to iterate over `range(n)` and take input as well as append them on string

Comment: @realtun what I have put in my code as `lst = ['-1', '0.5', 'abc', '32']` what will be in `lst` in your code after you enter -1, 0.5, abc and 32